# Importance of the Transcendence of $\pi$ and $e$

Tags: transcendental-numbers

Why do people care that $\pi$ and $e$ are transcendental?

Comment: Because that means they are not algebraic.  Why would people care if a number is algebraic?  Because algebraic numbers are solutions to some equation of the form $c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+c_3x^3+\dots+c_nx^n = 0$ for some sequence of rational numbers $c_i$ and finite natural number $n$.

Comment: @JMoravitz We can even assume that the $c_i$ are integers.

Comment: something to meditate on ;)

Comment: The real question is "why do transcendental numbers matter", see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2873600/what-is-the-usefulness-of-classification-into-transcedental-and-algebraic-number/2874391#2874391).

Answer (score 4):

One use for knowing whether $\pi $ is transcendental is the very old problem of [squaring the circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_circle). For thousands of years we were unable to answer it, it was only in $1882$ that we solved it, as a consequence of the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: +1, btw @user109871 if this motivation is interesting to you [Field Theory and its Classical Problems](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Classical-Problems-Mathematical-Association-Textbooks/dp/088385032X#reader_088385032X) has a truly delightful exposition of the the history of the problem leading up to the transcendence of $\pi$ in Chapter 1 *The Three Greek Problems*, before going onto insolvability of the quintic. (Matheus Andrade hope you don't mind tagging a reference onto your post but reminded of sth hugely enjoyed reading about decades ago!)

Comment: @Mehness, no problem, I appreciate the suggestion as well!

Comment: definitely worth checking out - read it for a 1st yr undergrad project on Galois theory up to Abel's Theorem, which it gets to all the way from ruler and compass in about 200 small pages :)